# How to return result of javascript variable inside javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop that I want to return later in a javascript file.

At the moment I have some lines hardcoded like this:

```
var props = [{
      title : 'Bouwbedrijf van de Water',
        image : 'bbvdw.jpg',
        address : 'Polyanderweg 2, 3218 XT Heenvliet',
        position : {
            lat : 51.863010, // 51.8424513,
            lng : 4.235398 // 4.3307054
        },
        markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
    },{
      title : 'Studio NewMedia B.V.',
        image : 'snm.jpg',
        address : 'goudenregeplein 1, 1234 AB, Spijkenisse',
        position : {
            lat : 51.842451, // 51.8424513,
            lng : 4.332894 // 4.3307054
        },
        markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
    },{
      title : 'Taxi Overgaauw',
        image : 'taxi.jpg',
        address : '3214 LJ Zuidland',
        position : {
            lat : 51.822302, // 51.8424513,
            lng : 4.247739 // 4.3307054
        },
        markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
    },{
      title : 'Moree & Vermeer B.V.',
        image : 'moree.jpg',
        address : 'Ring 2 3212LS Simonshaven',
        position : {
            lat : 51.823013, // 51.8424513,
            lng : 4.290310 // 4.3307054
        },
        markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
    },{
      title : 'Molengraaf Makelaardij',
        image : 'molengraaf.jpg',
        address : 'Mr P.J. Oudweg 56 3214 XN Zuidland',
        position : {
            lat : 51.821451, // 51.8424513,
            lng : 4.259176 // 4.3307054
        },
        markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
    },
    {
      title : 'P. Vis B.V.',
        image : 'pvisbv.jpg',
        address : 'Drieëndijk 1a – 3218 LB Heenvliet',
        position : {
          lat : 51.857122, // 51.8418945,
          lng : 4.236260 // 4.3337659
        },
        markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
    }];
```

This is hardcoded, but I want to be able to add new markers to the map, so I created a json object and looped it like this:

```
$.each( bedrijven, function( key, value ) {
      // console.log( key + ": " + value.plaats );
      bedrijvenlijst += `{
        title : '${value.title}',
          image : 'bbvdw.jpg',
          address : '${value.straat} ${value.plaats}',
          position : {
              lat : 51.863010, // 51.8424513,
              lng : 4.235398 // 4.3307054
          },
          markerIcon : 'marker-green.png'
      },`;
    });
```

Now my question is, how can I replace the hardcoded lines for the result of the loop?

If it was a php variable I could simple use

```
echo $bedrijvenlijst;
```

later in the file. But in javascript this works differently.

I tried the following:

```
var props = [
    document.writeIn(bedrijvenlijst);
    {
      title : 'P. Vis B.V.',
        image : 'pvisbv.jpg',
        address : 'Drieëndijk 1a – 3218 LB Heenvliet',
        position : {
          lat : 51.857122, // 51.8418945,
          lng : 4.236260 // 4.3337659
        },
        markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
    }];
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Which points to this line: `document.writeIn(bedrijvenlijst);`

I know my loop always ends with a comma and the last one doesn't need to have one, but that is an issue for another time, first I need to know how to return the result of my loop inside that var `props`.

Comment: `var props = [` defines a declaration of variable and its initialization. `document.writeIn(bedrijvenlijst);` is a statement. You cannot have a statement during initialization.

Comment: And btw, why do you make it a `string` with your loop?

Comment: While you're working with json format, why not considering Object.assign() ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @Rajesh Alright, so how can I fix that? My javascript is pretty bad, it must be possible to add the result inside that var.

Comment: @dgiugg I don't know another way how to loop it. I mostly work with PHP and now need to use JS for this map. Will this be an issue?

Comment: do you want a `prop` variable with JSON value in html?

Comment: I want to load the looped result of `bedrijvenlijst` inside `props` so that when the javascript file is read by the browser, it reads the loaded markers from my looped json object inside `props`. @MirazChowdhury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS you need an array. And you have to work with array. Please have a look at code,

```
var bedrijvenlijst = []; // new array
$.each( bedrijven, function( key, value ) {
  // console.log( key + ": " + value.plaats );
  bedrijvenlijst.push({
      title : value.title,
      image : 'bbvdw.jpg',
      address : value.straat + ' ' + value.plaats,
      position : {
          lat : 51.863010, // 51.8424513,
          lng : 4.235398 // 4.3307054
      },
      markerIcon : 'marker-green.png'
  }); // new item added in array
});

var props = bedrijvenlijst; // assign the new array
props.push({  // add a new item on props array
  title : 'P. Vis B.V.',
    image : 'pvisbv.jpg',
    address : 'Drieëndijk 1a – 3218 LB Heenvliet',
    position : {
      lat : 51.857122, // 51.8418945,
      lng : 4.236260 // 4.3337659
    },
    markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this did what I wanted!